# How access private methods from anonymous class?

Tags: java, object, reflection, methods

Suppose I have class:

```
MyObject b = new MyObject(){
    private void method(){}
}
```

Is it possible to get method() by reflection? For toString I can write:

```
MyObject.class.getMethod("toString");
```

But what about for new created private method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to invoke [`Object#getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) on `b` reference to get the anonymous class, where the method is declared. `MyObject.class` will give you `Class<MyObject>`, which is not possibly what you want.

And then use [`Class#getDeclaredMethod()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) to get the private method:

```
Method method = b.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("method");
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke()
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use it with:

```
Method method = b.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("method");
```

Here `b.getClass()` will return the class that the compiler generated for you for the anonymous inner class.

I can't easily imagine a situation in which that's a good approach, however.

Note that if you use a local *named* class, you don't even need to use reflection to call the method:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        class Foo {
            private void doSomething() {
                System.out.println("Yes!");
            }
        };

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.doSomething();
    }
}
```

If you could give us more context about why you want this, we could probably be of more help in finding the best solution.